# cmake include_directories for boost

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake

I'm adopting cmake script for a windows build,
and faced with an issue which was not occured under *nix

```
set(BOOST_ROOT, "C:/dev/tools/boost_1_60_0")
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES} ${BOOST_ROOT} include)
```

It doesn't work - during the compilation , vc can't find boost headers.

```
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES} "C:/dev/tools/boost_1_60_0" include)
```

this works well.

any ideas why it happens?

just for sure, for this configuration pre-compiled libraries are not required so then I don't perform find_package, just using a headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it's not a typo, the "," is not needed in the set directive :

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/dev/tools/boost_1_60_0")
```

this should work as expected.

Comment: man! my inattention. yes, it was a root of the issue. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Why not [`FindBoost()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html)?

```
find_package(Boost 1.60 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: first of all, it doesn't helpful in my case, find_package looks for a hints where boost can be installed, and hint doesn't work for me, thatis a problem. in other hand , find_package is reasonable for binary libraries only, especially when we need to build library name from a few parameters like a boost version, compiler version, etc. in case of header only libraries, BOOST_ROOT = <boost include folder>, nothing to find

Comment: @amigo421 You don't need hint, just add your Boost path to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`